# Closed form of product of Gamma function

Tags: symbolic, special-functions, products

Mathematica
recognizes this closed form
\begin{align} 
\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}\sin(\pi k/n)
&=
2^{1-n}\,n
\end{align}
just fine:

[image]

but fails 
on this one

[image]

despite that this expression also has a known closed form
\begin{align} 
\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}\Gamma(k/n)
&=
\sqrt{\frac{ (2\,\pi)^{n-1}}{n}}
.
\end{align}

Is there a way to make Mathematica
to recognize it?

Comment: This is peculiar, since for a finite product, there is no obvious reason why it should need to consider any evaluation with a non-finite result.

Comment: I've confirmed this behaviour in V12.0.  It would be interesting to know if earlier versions give the same result.

Comment: Also fails on Mac OS 11.3

Comment: @mikado: Also fails on 11.3.0 for Linux ARM (32-bit)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Workaround:

$$\Gamma \left(\frac{k}{n}\right)=\frac{\Gamma \left(\frac{k}{n}+1\right)}{\frac{k}{n}}$$

```
$Version
(* "12.0.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (April 6, 2019)" *)

Product[Gamma[k/n + 1]/(k/n), {k, 1, n - 1}]
(* (2 π)^(1/2 (-1 + n))/Sqrt[n] *)
```

Comment: How would you display it as shown in the question? //TraditionalForm does not.

Comment: @nilo, `(2 π)^(1/2 (-1 + n))/Sqrt[n] // (TraditionalForm[Sqrt[#^2]] &)` at least works for this case.

Comment: Wow! Did not know that was possible. So cool.

Answer (score 5):

The indeterminate can be overcome using the full identity for $\Gamma(nz)$:

$$\Gamma(nz)=(2\pi)^{(1-n)/2}n^{nz-1/2}\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}\Gamma(z+\frac{k}{n})$$

and taking the limit as $z\rightarrow 0$:

```
$Version
(* "12.0.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (April 15, 2019)" *)

Limit[Product[Gamma[z + k/n], {k, 1, n - 1}], z -> 0]
(* (2 \[Pi])^(1/2 (-1 + n))/Sqrt[n] *)
```